# Algorithm for the combinations of M natural numbers which create a given number (N) with repetition

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm which print all of the combinations of M natural numbers which create a given number (N) with repetition.

Let's say the that our java function is: public static String[] foo(6,3) where 6 is N and 3 is M.
The answer should be:

```
0,0,6
0,1,5
0,2,4
0,3,3
1,1,4
1,2,3
2,2,2

and foo(7,4):
0,0,0,7
0,0,1,6
0,0,2,5
0,0,3,4
0,1,1,5
0,1,2,4
0,1,3,3
1,1,1,4
1,1,2,3
1,2,2,2 (if im not wrong...)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is called a *partition function*.

Comment: You must show us your effort. This is the rule. Add the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive approach, observing that you start with a requirement for M numbers, which can be broken down into a simpler problem with M-1 numbers, until M=1.

```
public class RecursiveCombinations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        solve(4,7,0,"");
    }

private static void solve(int M, int remainingValue, int previousLevel, String solutionSoFar) {
    if (M == 1) {
        System.out.println(solutionSoFar+remainingValue);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = previousLevel; i<=remainingValue/M; i++) {
        String s = solutionSoFar+i+",";
        solve(M-1, remainingValue-i, i, s);
    }
}
```

creating output:

```
0,0,0,7
0,0,1,6
0,0,2,5
0,0,3,4
0,1,1,5
0,1,2,4
0,1,3,3
0,2,2,3
1,1,1,4
1,1,2,3
1,2,2,2
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to generate arrays with length M and all possible combinations of numbers up to N and test every single one for the right result.
Very brute force, but would work. You could build up from there(Eliminate doubled results ...)

You might also want to look at [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

This could look like this:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Tests 
{

    public static void main(String[] aargh)
    {
        LinkedList<int[]> arr = numarrays(7,4);
        for(int i = 0; i< arr.size();i++)
        {
            int[] curr = arr.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < curr.length;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(curr[j]+" ,"); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static LinkedList<int[]> numarrays(int result, int depth)
    {
        LinkedList<int[]> retVal = new LinkedList<int[]>();

        int[][] val = new int[1][];

        while(next(result,depth,val))
        {
            if(reject(result, val[0])) continue;
            if(!accept(result, val[0])) continue;   
            retVal.add(val[0].clone());
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    private static boolean reject(int max, int[] in) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< in.length; i++)
        {
            sum += in[i];
            if(sum > max) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static boolean accept(int target, int[] in) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< in.length; i++)
        {
            sum += in[i];
        }

        if(sum == target) return true;

        return false;
    }

    private static boolean next(int max, int depth, int[][] val) 
    {
        if(val[0] == null)
        {
            val[0] = new int[depth];
            return true;
        }

        return nextrec(max,val[0],0);
    }

    private static boolean nextrec(int max, int[] curr, int i) 
    {
        if(i>=curr.length) return false;

        if(nextrec(curr[i],curr,i+1)) return true;

        if(curr[i]< max)
        {
            curr[i]++;
            zerorec(curr,i+1);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static void zerorec(int[] curr, int i) 
    {
        if(i>=curr.length) return ;
        curr[i] = 0; 
        zerorec(curr,i+1);
    }
}
```